# How to enable syntax highlighting for django template files in Atom Text Editor?

Tags: django, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I am new to Django. Getting started with new syntax is easier if you have syntax highlighting. Any help is appretiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use **django-templates** this package for highlight the syntax for django template files.

https://atom.io/packages/django-templates